# webページでデータを監視する事は出来るのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

現在EPSON TM-m10と言うレシートプリンタの制御で遊んでいます。
メーカー提供のJavaScriptライブラリのサンプルコードを使用し、Apacheサーバー上にtest.phpと言うスクリプトを作成し、ブラウザから以下のようなURLでアクセスすることで印刷は出来るようになりました。

`http://192.168.100.100/test.php?id=123&data=456&price=12300`

しかし、毎回プリンタとの接続からデバイスオブジェクトの作成など、コールバック関数の待ち時間が長い状況です。

今回の質問は、新たにmachiuke.phpと言うスクリプトで、印刷直前（プリンタオブジェクトまで作成して待っている）の状況で状態を監視、リクエストが来たときにすぐに印刷できないかな？と考えています。
何分初心者故のため、的を射ていない質問で申し訳ありません。
数台のPCからリクエストしたいので、単一PCでブラウザを開いておく事は難しいです。

そもそもこのやり方は間違っているなどがあれば教えて頂ければと思います。

Comment: 仕組み的にはそれらを行うマイクロサービス的なプリントサーバープロセスを作成・起動して、Apacheサーバーからその機能を呼び出せば良いと思われます。が、「毎回...など、コールバック関数の待ち時間が長い状況です。」というのは何がどれくらい掛かっているのか細かく計測していますか？ 有ればその数値を追記し、無ければその計測を行ってみてはどうでしょう？ あとこの質問の場合、サーバー/クライアント/プリンタの関係と、それらの何処が何を担当して、依頼や通知がどのように行われるかを図やシーケンスで提示した方が自身でやりたい事の整理にもなって良いかと思われます。

Comment: あるいはもしかして1行毎にサーバーおよびプリンタへ印刷依頼していますか？ その場合はとても非効率なので1つのレシートの最初から最後(+用紙カット)までを(クライアントかサーバーのどちらかで)バッファリングして、最後にまとめて印刷依頼するのが普通でしょう。

Comment: Epson ePOS SDK for JavaScriptを使用しており、ePOSDeviceオブジェクトから、connect()を行い、それが成功したらcreateDevice()を行い、それがそれぞれ5秒くらいかかります。それが成功するとprinterオブジェクトが取得でき、addText()、addBarcode()、addCut()等でデータを作り、最後にsend()で送るというやり方です。カットまでのデータは一度に送信しております。printerオブジェクトを取得した時点で待ち受けをしておく事は出来ないのかなと思ってみました。わかりにくくてすみません。

Comment: その場合、`ePOS_SDK_JavaScript_um_ja_revV.pdf`の543ページに記述されている「Webページを頻繁に更新/遷移するアプリケーションを開発するには」のオプションパラメータを試してみましたか？ 他には533-534ページに記述されている「常時監視するには」「ネットワークを自動で再接続するには」がヒントになるかもしれませんね。

Comment: kunif様のコメント通りでした。{"eposprint": true}のオプションを付けて実行したところ、１５秒くらいの処理が１秒かからなくなりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントのやりとりにて解決したようなので、記録として回答します。

メーカー提供のJavascriptライブラリとはこちら。
[アプリケーション開発キット Epson ePOS SDK](https://partner.epson.jp/support/details/contents164/)
[ドライバー・ソフトウェア基本情報（Epson ePOS SDK for JavaScript）](https://www.epson.jp/dl_soft/readme/35962.htm)

ただし、こちら英語サイトの方が新しい版数になっています。
[Epson ePOS SDK for JavaScript](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=7169&pcat=3&pid=4654)

上記ライブラリに含まれる`ePOS_SDK_JavaScript_um_ja_revV.pdf`というドキュメント(日本語サイトの方はファイル名の最後が`revU`となっていて1つ古い)の543ページ(`revU`版は533ページ)に説明記事があり、関連する部分を抜粋します。

> **Webページを頻繁に更新/遷移するアプリケーションを開発するには**
> Epson ePOS SDK for JavaScript で開発したアプリケーションは、Web ページを更新 / 遷移する度に接続デバイスとの通信を切断し、再接続する処理が発生します。このため印字開始やディスプレイ表示が遅くなることがあります。
> ePOS-Print オプションを有効にすることで、接続処理にかかる時間を短縮できます。
>
> ePOS-Print オプションは、connect メソッドの option パラメーターで設定します。
> 例）ePOS-Print オプションを有効にする。
>
> ```
> connect("192.168.192.168", "8008", callback, {"eposprint" : true});
> ```

制限事項もありますので詳しくはドキュメントを参照してください。

---

コメントによると15秒程度かかっていたのが1秒かからないくらいになったとのこと。